# График с сортировкий по убыванию

Tags: vue.js, диаграммы

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, компонент для Vue - график, в котором каждый label может быть отсортирован по убыванию.

У меня есть данные:

```js
labels: [day1, day2, day3]
 datasets: [
   {label: 'Nike', data: [10, 30, 40]},
   {label: 'Adidas', data: [20, 15, 35]},
   {label: 'Puma', data: [5, 20, 15]}
]
```

Мне нужно получить такой вид для каждого дня:
Day1 - **20, 10, 5** (Сейчас могу получить только вид типа - **10, 20, 5**, использую vue-chart)
т.е. компонент должен принимать что-то вроде:

```js
    labels: [day1, day2, day3]
    datasets: [
       {label: 'day1', data: ['Nike': 10, 'Adidas': 20, 'Puma': 5]},
       {label: 'day2', data: ['Nike': 30, 'Adidas': 15, 'Puma': 20]},
       {label: 'day3', data: ['Nike': 40, 'Adidas': 35, 'Puma': 15]}
    ]
```

Буду очень благодарна за совет!

Comment: Дак сделайте в дате переменную labelsSort, в которую записывайте день, по которому нужна сортировка, а потом watch'ем отслеживаете её изменение и сортируете массив. Ну или если не хотите трогать оригинал, сделайте computed свойство, которое будет возвращать отсортированный как вам надо массив (или возвращать оригинал, когда labelsSort пустое) и уже его скармливайте vue-chart

Comment: @АлександрРогонов, Сортировать массивы data нельзя - данные в них располагаются для каждого дня {label: 'Nike', data: [10 (день 1), 30(день 2), 40(день 3]}, Т.е Nike на графике зя любой день будет на первом месте, Adidas на втором и т.д. [https://www.screencast.com/t/xhig8qIlDnmy]. vue-chart принимает данные только в таком формате. Я хочу найти компонент для построения графика, который бы принимал что-то вроде {label: 'day1', data: ['Nike': 10, 'Adidas': 20, 'Puma': 5]}, тогда отсортировать не было бы проблем

Comment: график https://www.screencast.com/t/xhig8qIlDnmy

Comment: Под датой я подразумевал не ваше поле data, а вообщем и целом все данные целиком (datasets). Прошу прощение. Давайте еще разок, что вы хотите получить то? Условно говоря, если пользователь нажмет на "day1" вы хотите вот такой результат `datasets: [{label: 'Adidas', data: [20, 15, 35]}, {label: 'Nike', data: [10, 30, 40]}, {label: 'Puma', data: [5, 20, 15]}]`?

Comment: Пользователь не может никуда нажать. Все данные просто отображаются на графике. Задача - отсортировать по убыванию данные для каждого дня. На графике будут сразу все дни - https://www.screencast.com/t/xhig8qIlDnmy И vue-chart для этого не подходит. Пытаюсь найти подходящий компонент.